# Pause an animation loop cycle

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, graph-editor

I have a cow that needs to pause between two gates for a couple of seconds. I created her walk cycle and used "Make cyclic (F-modifier)" in the graph editor. With this set up I can't figure out how to pause her walk cycle while she briefly stands still while still being able to resume the animation cycle where it left off...

[image]

The bone animation is cycled like so...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the graph editor press spacebar and search for "Bake action", set the time interval and bake.

In the dopesheet erase all the keyframes where you want the cow to stop.

Another way is using NLA editor to cycle; another way is manually copying the cycle in the dopesheet (this latter is very fast and allows maximum control, in my opinion).

Comment: Copying the dope sheet was the only way I could make it work. The only issue is that any later changes I make to the animation will not propagate to the previously copied key frames. Wish there was a way to simply ignore the animation for a set number of frames in order to keep a true cycle in tact.

Comment: The NLA editor lets you combine different pieces of animation and copy, repeat, sum, multiply ease their actions, so if you edit an action your edit will propagate in all the copies. The cycle modifier has some frames limits that you can set, put it seems difficult to set two different cycles in the same action (you would need one from start to stop, and one from restart to end).

Comment: When I "push action down" in NLA, I can then use Action Editor mode inside the Dopesheet. Then I click a down arrow which switches to editing action. I guess this essentially unpacks the animation from the NLA for editing. Problem is, the up arrow to repack to NLA only works sometimes and seems to fail after particular animation edits. Without repacking, every copy made in the NLA is dead. Am I doing this right? thx